# using cliente.DownloadString(url); give weird square symbols c# .net 3.5

Tags: c#, webclient, symbols

I'm using webclient to get the source html code from websites and put the html in a textbox

but for some reason in the textbox I'm gettig weird symbol

```
      using (WebClient cliente = new WebClient())
            {
                textbox.Text = cliente.DownloadString(url);
            }
```

I'm using c# .net 3.5

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/691/weirdssymbols.jpg/

Comment: You didnt really ask any question, you just said whats going on. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I want new line instead the square and accent instead &acute.

Comment: It is not newline or carriage return, TextBox already handles those.  Use textBox.Text.ToCharArray() in the debugger to find the character code.

Answer (score 0):

Those are representations of non-printable new line characters.

Try

```
 textBox.Multiline = true; 
 using (WebClient cliente = new WebClient())
 {
      textbox.Text = cliente.DownloadString(url);
 }
```

Comment: They indeed seem to be carriage return and newline characters (\r\n)

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's a problem connected to encoding.
Is your string utf-8 encoded?

You need to set the webclient encoding equals to web page enconding (if you manage the page, set it to utf-8, is a better solution).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.encoding%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Then, I think you wouldn't get bad squares anymore, however I don't know encoding used by textboxes, this could be a problem (I again suppose they use utf-8, don't know if they are configurable).

**EDIT:**

Didn't see your comment, yes definitely I think those squares are \r\n characters, which (maybe) are written on the page with an encoding different from uft-8 (so it's not your fault but it's a problem that the webpage's developer created).

&acute can't be converted, you must replace with string.replace with what you want (&acute is used by html to show some special characters)

Comment: yes the website is encode in utf8 <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  so i'm using this cliente.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
but still i'm getting the  square instead newlines.

Comment: As I wrote in the edit, I think those are newlines written on a utf-8 webpage with an editor that wasn't using utf-8. That's a big problem because you don't know original encoding :\

Comment: I've use all this and no success
cliente.Encoding = Encoding.UTF7;
cliente.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
cliente.Encoding = Encoding.UTF32;
cliente.Encoding = Encoding.Unicode;
cliente.Encoding = Encoding.ASCII;
cliente.Encoding = Encoding.Default;

Comment: Maybe they used some iso-something-something encoding, but I really don't know how to discover this, sorry

Comment: solution to get ride of square use richtextbox instead textbox, or replace the square char in textbox(singleline) like this
 texbox.Text = texbox.Text.ToString().Replace(tbsquaresymbol.Text, Environment.NewLine);

Yeah!

Comment: Yes obviusly that a solution if you don't know encoding, good luck man ;)